# Custom interpreter

Tags: forth

I'm trying to write an interpreter in [Gforth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gforth), but it doesn't work. All I get is an infinite list of num num num num ...

```
: ?refill
  source nip >in @ =
  if
    refill drop
  then
  ;

: inter
  begin
    ?refill
    bl word find dup
    if
      state @ =
      if
        ." comp "
        ,
      else
        ." exec "
        execute
      then
    else
      dup rot count >number
      if
        abort
      then
      drop drop state @
      if
        ." lit "
        ['] lit , ,
      else
        ." num "
      then
    then
  again
  ;

inter

: test 10 20 ;
```

Comment: So you've defined two 'words'.  What's your input data?

Comment: @AKE he calls `inter`, and as it uses `source`, the input data comes from the same stream as the source-code, so in this case the input data is everything after `inter`, which is essentially the last line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your interpreter does work, it just does not block, see the first couple of words from the output:

```
num exec lit lit exec num num num ...
```

However, you leave a `0` on the stack somewhere, thats why you create a stack overflow, you can use `~~` in the code to check the stack and track the unconsumed `0`.

Bernd Paysan has introduced [Recognizers](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/anton/euroforth/ef12/papers/paysan-recognizers-ho.pdf) to GForth, I suggest you take a look at them, as they would ease your task of writing an interpreter.